# CSS smart position?

Tags: jquery, html, css, position

I'm wondering if there is any way to sort the divs smart, this is what I want to do.

I'm getting users from a json file, sometimes 5, sometimes 4, 3​​, sometimes 1 ... the problem is that when each side is 5. I get the remaining divs perfect, but when they are 4  or 3 users by side, divs are disassembled and I do not know how to sort properly, leave a couple of photos showing what happens to me.

[image: This is what i need]
[image: This is what get]
The second image show what happen if theres only 2 o 3 users at left side, other divs shown as "empty". I hope I explained, if not, let me  know please.

the css of the divs:

```
  .userTraced {
    width: 160px;
    height: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    background-color: #DDDDDD;

  }
  .a100 {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
  }
  .a200 {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    top: -104px;
  }
  .aNai {
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
```

"aNai" style is for the the "empty" divs. and the html:

```
<div class="userTraced a100"> </div>
<div class="userTraced a100"> </div>
<div class="userTraced a100"> </div>
<div class="userTraced a200"> </div>
<div class="userTraced a200"> </div>
<div class="userTraced a200"> </div>
<div class="userTraced a100 aNai"> </div>
<div class="userTraced a100 aNai"> </div>
<div class="userTraced a200 aNai"> </div>
<div class="userTraced a200 aNai"> </div>
```

Theres always 10 divs total.

this is what im doing to get the data

```
if (!empty($recentFall[$thisGame]->fellowPlayers->array[0]->summonerId)){

  $player_1_Name = $players_ES[array_search($recentFall[$thisGame]->fellowPlayers->array[0]->summonerId, $players_ids)];

//----->
if ($recentFall[$thisGame]->fellowPlayers->array[0]->teamId == "100"){
    $addTeam100++; 
    $addClass_1 = "";
    $checkBlue++;
}else{
    $addTeam200++;
    $addClass_1 = "";
}
//----->

} else {
$player_1_Name = "Vacio / BOT";

//----->
if ($addTeam100 < 5) {
    $addClass_1 = "a100";
    $addTeam100++; 
}else{
    $addClass_1 = "a200";
    $addTeam200++; 
}
//----->
}
```

Comment: How are you retrieving the JSON content? Can we see the loop?

Comment: You could possibly use the jquery plugin Masonry to allow the divs to sit next to each other: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: The second image show what happen if theres only 2 o 3 users at left side, other divs shown as "empty" ...........?

Comment: i am sorry, i dont know what are you talking about =)

Comment: thats a good one Chris i will try it, thanks!

Comment: @Chris im trying wuth Masonry, [Mansory Example](http://jsbin.com/vabupo/1/edit?html,css,output), i need to take all the blue divs to the left, is that posible?